# Best way to search a content ( specific ID ) from a huge file ( contains 10 millions of lines ) by using java

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a huge file containing at least 10 millions of lines and I need to search a particular unique word (ID) from that file using java. Please suggest me the best and fastest way which will consume very less processing time to achieve this.

Is `java.util.concurrent` package will be useful. If yes please suggest me how?

Comment: are you looking for Data Structure option or native JAVA method?

Comment: Is that 1,010,000,000 lines, or 10 million lines? Also, how often will the file change? Is it worth creating an index to the words in the file?

Comment: If you need to read the file from a hard drive, the bottleneck is going to be I/O and parallelising won't help...

Comment: That file will be updated very frequently (in every minute). I need the solution to achieve this by using java 7.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. It is 10 millions

Comment: how will the file be updates? can you index it before/while its gettin updated?

Comment: No Some other application is updating the file, so I cannot add index. My task is just to read and search that ID and do some operation for that ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the reading and searching operation into separate threads. That way, you searching will not interrupt your reading. However, as IO will be the major bottleneck, I doubt you will see much of an performance increase.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code: hopefully it'll finish within your time limit of 1min

```
String search="searchMe";     
String  thisLine = null;
      try{
         // open input stream test.txt for reading purpose.
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("MYFILE");
         boolean found=true;
         while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(thisLine.equals(search)){
              System.out.println(search + " was found.");
              found=true
              break;
            }
         }
         if(!found){
             System.out.println("not found");
         }
         br.close();       
      }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

It might be faster if you use some other program to split the file into smaller "temporary" files. and use threads to work on each file.(Not 100% sure if that would work).

Obviously the best solution would be to be able to edit the program that generates this file and make it to create few different files (possibly in different hard drives). then u can easily use threading to increase the speed.